# Limit of trig function with infinitely many zeros

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am looking for an explanation, suppose we have the following function

$$
f(a,n)\text{=}\frac{\sqrt{n} (2 a \sin (a \log (n))+\cos (a \log (n)))-1}{4 a^2+1},n\to \infty ,a\in \mathbb{R},n\in \mathbb{N}
$$

By my observation I found that if $n\to\infty$ then number of zeros is growing at any fixed interval $[a_1,a_2]$.

Can I conclude that at $\infty$, number of zeros at any fixed interval $[a_1,a_2]$ will be tends to $\infty$, and hence

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}f(a,n)=0
$$

If not, is it correct to say that in the limit a function will have infinitely many zeros?

Comment: Have you proved that the limit exists?  That would be the first step.  I'm dubious.

Comment: No, I'm just trying to understand what is happening here.

Comment: I don't know, but I would guess it's oscillating at ever-increasing frequency, and that the limit doesn't exist.  Something like $\sin(nx)$.

Comment: Yes, that’s right, in the case of  $sin(nx)$ the same thing happens. Correct me if I'm wrong. $sin(nx)$, if $n\to \infty$, and we consider the function depending on $x$, then in any fixed interval $[x_1,x_2]$, the number of zeros will tend to $n\to \infty$, right? If so hence limit is zero?

Comment: But in case of $sin(n)$, $n\to \infty$, of course it's D.N.E.

Comment: Yes, and there's no reason to believe that the limit exists in this case, either.  How many times does the function take the value $1$ in an interval?  Should the limit be $1$ as well as $0$?

Comment: Yes that's right. The function takes many other values. 
In this case is it correct to say that in the limit a function will have infinitely many zeros?

Comment: @saulspatz Wouldn't it be _decreasing_ frequency?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Increasing frequency, decreasing wavelength.

Comment: @saulspatz : Maybe you're thinking of it as a function of $a$ rather than of $n. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, I am.  The OP is talking about a sequence of functions of $x$.  I am talking about how the frequency of those functions changes as $n$ increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a$ and $-1$ are fixed as $n\to\infty,$ we may as well just consider
$$
\sqrt{n} (2 a \sin (a \log n)+\cos (a \log n)).
$$
First recall trigonometric identity:
\begin{align}
A\sin x+B\cos x = {} & \sqrt{A^2+B^2} \sin(x+\varphi) \\[8pt]
&\text{where } \tan\varphi= B/A.
\end{align}
Thus you have
$$
n\mapsto\sqrt n\sqrt{4a^2+1}\big( \sin((a\log n) + \varphi)\big). \tag 1
$$
The rate of growth of $n\mapsto\log n$ can be made as small as desired by making $n$ big enough, but it still approaches $+\infty.$ Therefore the function in line $(1)$ above will go through infinitely many periods of the sine function, and this sine function will get as close to $+1$ and to $-1$ as you wish infinitely many times. And it's multiplied by $\sqrt n$ which grows without bound.

Comment: Many thanks for explanation.
The answer to first question: limit is does not exist. Got it.

But little more, it's correct to say that $f(a,n)$, $n\to \infty$ can take infinitely many zeros?

Moreover in any fixed interval $[a_1,a_2]$, $f(a,n)$, $n\to \infty$ must have infinitely many zeros.

It's hard to tell, suppose we have simple expression: $f(x)=x-1$, $x=1$ is zero, i want to know if we multiply $n f(x)$ and $n\to \infty$.
$n(x-1)=0$, when $x=1$ correct?
I ask this because I am little bit confused by an expression like $\infty \cdot 0$.